# Images not changing size with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am unable to change the size of my article images with flex. I'm new to flex (and new to coding) and have read this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ but still can't solve my issue. I'd appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

CSS

```
.prezi-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

article {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="prezi-container">
  <article>
    <a href="http://www.domain/image1.com">
      <img class="presentation" src="images/image1" alt="Some alt text.">
    </a>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Click image to see presentation.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <a href="http://www.domain/image2.com">
      <img class="presentation" src="images/image2" alt="Some alt text.">
    </a>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Click image to see presentation.</p>
  </article>
   <article>
    <a href="http://www.domain/image3.com">
      <img class="presentation" src="images/image3" alt="Some alt text.">
    </a>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Click image to see presentation.</p>
  </article>
 </section>
```

Comment: have you tried using `.presentation` selector to set the image size or just `img` [see this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: `display: flex` in `.prezi-container` only affects the `<article>`, but **not** what's inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
article {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

basically your first part of CSS code makes your article elements have equal size with each other regardless of the space available ( flex: 1 1 ). The 100% ensures that they 100% fill the size of their container. So you have two option here, either set the size of the container to specific values and then your article tags and images will equally distribute themselves to that size or you can set  the size of the img tag. In both cases you need to use width and height properties. see below:

```
.presentation {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Please note that you have to include / to end article 2 and 3 because you forgot to include /

Comment: Thank you!  I did forget to end the articles in the pasting process. I will try this.

Comment: Hmm, this still is not working. .prezi-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.presentation {
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
}

article {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

Comment: Can you see your images in the page? because images must be displayed for the code to work. In your answer you just make images fill 100% of the width of container so you don't have full control of image size

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked. I got advice from my mom who codes. Yay!

```
.prezi-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.presentation{
  max-width: 100%;
}

article {
  flex: 1 1;
}
```